# CFArrayRef memory leak

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using [LaunchAtLoginController](https://github.com/Mozketo/LaunchAtLoginController)  for one of my project and in the following method there is always a `NSArray` leaking memory. As you can see I cast a `CFArrayRef` to a `NSArray (__bridge NSArray*)`. I thought I could solve it using `__bridge_transfer`, but the app crashes `(EXC_BAD_ACCESS)`. Is it because one of the items in the array is returned by the method?

```
- (LSSharedFileListItemRef) findItemWithURL: (NSURL*) wantedURL inFileList: (LSSharedFileListRef) fileList
{
    if (wantedURL == NULL || fileList == NULL)
    return NULL;

    NSArray *listSnapshot = (__bridge NSArray*)(LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(fileList, NULL));

    LSSharedFileListItemRef itemToReturn = NULL;
    for (id itemObject in listSnapshot) {
        LSSharedFileListItemRef item = (__bridge LSSharedFileListItemRef) itemObject;
        UInt32 resolutionFlags = kLSSharedFileListNoUserInteraction | kLSSharedFileListDoNotMountVolumes;
        CFURLRef currentItemURL = NULL;
        LSSharedFileListItemResolve(item, resolutionFlags, &currentItemURL, NULL);
        if (currentItemURL && CFEqual(currentItemURL, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(wantedURL)))
        {
            CFRelease(currentItemURL);
            itemToReturn = item;
        } else {
            if (currentItemURL)
            CFRelease(currentItemURL);
            if (item)
                CFRelease(item);
        }
    }
    return itemToReturn;
}
```

This are two methods that call `(LSSharedFileListItemRef) findItemWithURL: (NSURL*) wantedURL inFileList: (LSSharedFileListRef)` fileList. Although I managed to release the item returned, I can never release the NSArray that, obviously, leaks memory.

```
- (BOOL) willLaunchAtLogin: (NSURL*) itemURL
{
    LSSharedFileListItemRef item = [self findItemWithURL:itemURL inFileList:loginItems];
    BOOL willLaunchAtLogin = !!item;
    if (item)
        CFRelease(item);
    return willLaunchAtLogin;
}

- (void) setLaunchAtLogin: (BOOL) enabled forURL: (NSURL*) itemURL
{
    LSSharedFileListItemRef appItem = [self findItemWithURL:itemURL inFileList:loginItems];
    if (enabled && !appItem) {
        LSSharedFileListItemRef itemRef = LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(loginItems, kLSSharedFileListItemBeforeFirst,
                                  NULL, NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef)itemURL, NULL, NULL);
        if (itemRef)
            CFRelease(itemRef);
    } else if (!enabled && appItem) {
        LSSharedFileListItemRemove(loginItems, appItem);
    }
    if (appItem)
        CFRelease(appItem);
}
```

I tried everything that I could think of to solve this but with no success. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to retain `itemToReturn` before `listSnapshot` is released.

Comment: when exactly? Before returning itemToReturn at the end of the method?

Comment: Before you release `listSnapshot`, which you don't. That's why it's leaking. It might be easier to write `findItemWithURL` in C without ARC and bridging.